# I am working on static and instance variables in Java, where I couldn't understand the output of the code

Tags: java, static, this, instance-variables

```
package java_course;

public class staticVsInstance {

    static int x = 11; 
    private int y = 33; 

    public void method1(int x) {
        staticVsInstance t = new staticVsInstance();
        System.out.println("t.x "+t.x + " " +"t.y  "+ t.y + " " +"x "+ x + " "+"y " + y);
        this.x = 22;
        this.y = 44;
        System.out.println("t.x "+t.x + " " +"t.y  "+ t.y + " " +"x "+ x + " "+"y " + y);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        staticVsInstance obj1 = new staticVsInstance();

        System.out.println(obj1.y);
        obj1.method1(10);
        System.out.println(obj1.y);
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
33
t.x 11 t.y  33 x 10 y 33
t.x 22 t.y  33 x 10 y 44
44
```

Does `this.y` refer to `obj1.y` or `t.y` in `method1`?

Why hasn't changing `this.y` any affect on `t.y`?

Comment: `y` is not static, that means that there is a difference instance per Object, and the `t` object is a different object to the `this` object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Your answer is extremely helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`y` is a global instance variable. When you call `obj1.method1(10);`, `this` in `method1` refers to `obj1`. So  `this.y` refer to `obj1.y` in method1.

> Why hasn't changing this.y any affect on t.y?

because `this` refers to `obj1` so you are changing instance variable of `obj1` not `t`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Your answer is extremely helpful